# Why is JSLint warning me about my switch-case statement being incorrectly formatted?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, warnings, jslint, adobe-brackets

In Adobe Brackets, I am getting warnings from JSLint when writing strict code ['use strict'] that my switch case statement is incorrectly formatted:
eg. Expected 'case' at column #, not column #

If I move everything inside the switch statement back back one "tab" JSLint is happy.
But, Adobe Brackets (And Similar Code Applications) wants to indent the case statements, and even when using Code Beautify it also formats the code to have an indent before the case statement.

> - When using strict code, is what JSLint is suggesting really the proper way of to format the switch-case statements?
> - Is there a way to fix/make JSLint in Adobe Brackets so it thinks this indentation is correct? (I would like to stick to not hacking up the JSLint Code)
> - Why would Editors format the switch-case statement this way if strict code does not want you to do that?
> - Am I really just doing something wrong here?
> - Is this just a downside of JSLint and is there a way to avoid using the switch-case statement then altogether thus in the process also making JSLint happy?
> - Should I really just stop using JSLint altogether? And Switch to something else?

This Code is nested in a for loop:

```js
switch (curButton.button.innerText.toLowerCase()) {
    case this.Part1.Button.ButtonText.toLowerCase():
        this.Part1.Button.ButtonText = curButton.button.innerText;
        this.Part1.Button.Element = curButton.button;
        this.Part1.Button.CurrentClass = curButton.button.className;
        console.log(smgData.PodCast.Parts.Part1.Button);
        break;
    case this.Part2.Button.ButtonText.toLowerCase():
        this.Part2.Button.ButtonText = curButton.button.innerText;
        this.Part2.Button.Element = curButton.button;
        this.Part2.Button.CurrentClass = curButton.button.className;
        console.log(smgData.PodCast.Parts.Part2.Button);
        break;
    case this.Part3.Button.ButtonText.toLowerCase():
        this.Part3.Button.ButtonText = curButton.button.innerText;
        this.Part3.Button.Element = curButton.button;
        this.Part2.Button.CurrentClass = curButton.button.className;
        console.log(smgData.PodCast.Parts.Part3.Button);
        break;
}
```

Here is some basic code that will reproduce this on https://www.jslint.com/

```js
function abcd() {
    var a;
    var b;
    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            a=b;
            break;
        case 2:
            b=a;
            break;
    }
}
```

[image: JSLint Warnings]

Comment: I can't reproduce it copying your code into the [online linter](https://www.jslint.com/). I'd highly recommend using a more active modern linter like ESLint instead, though, JSLint is... pretty lacking IMO

Comment: That said, it's often good to avoid `switch` entirely. Here, you can avoid it and make the code *much* shorter by using bracket notation instead, but that doesn't look like the solution you're asking for

Comment: I would be willing to re-format the question to ask for another way to write this code, If you have a suggestion about a better way to avoid using the switch statement, I am up for knowing that.

Comment: And ESLint is built into Adobe Brackets also, I guess I was just trying to make both of them happy.

Comment: Is `smgData.PodCast.Parts` the same as `this`? I'm wondering if, eg, `console.log(smgData.PodCast.Parts.Part1.Button);` could be turned into `console.log(this.Part1.Button);`

Comment: I added some code to the question that would reproduce that in the jslint website, and... Yes, I could use ```this.Part1.Button```, but I am only calling it that way for debugging, I am not leaving the ```console.log``` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with JSLint.

It's not exactly what you were asking, but one way to re-formulate the code and avoid `switch` entirely (and thus the problems JSLint has with `switch`) is to `.find` the `Part` whose `ButtonText` matches. Then use bracket notation to look up the button on the `this`:

```
const currentText = curButton.button.innerText.toLowerCase();
const matchingPart = ['Part1', 'Part2', 'Part3']
    .find(part => currentText === this[part].Button.ButtonText.toLowerCase());
if (matchingPart) {
    const { button } = this[matchingPart];
    button.ButtonText = curButton.button.innerText;
    button.Element = curButton.button;
    button.CurrentClass = curButton.button.className;
    console.log(smgData.PodCast.Parts[matchingPart].Button);
}
```

If you can control the shape of the `this` object, it would probably be easier if the `Part`s were an array, instead of 3 different properties. Then, you could `.find` over that array, instead of hard-coding the 3 `Part` properties.

I'd consider the code above to be *perfectly fine*, but to make it pass all of JSLint's (IMO - opinionated and not-so-good) rules, it'd have to be

```
const currentText = curButton.button.innerText.toLowerCase();
const props = ["Part1", "Part2", "Part3"];
const matchingPart = props.find(function(part) {
    return currentText === this[part].Button.ButtonText.toLowerCase();
});
if (matchingPart) {
    const { button } = this[matchingPart];
    button.ButtonText = curButton.button.innerText;
    button.Element = curButton.button;
    button.CurrentClass = curButton.button.className;
    console.log(smgData.PodCast.Parts[matchingPart].Button);
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why JSLint does not like the ```=>``` assignment?

Comment: For some reason, JSLint prefers the more verbose `function` when the function takes up multiple lines (which had to be done because JSLint didn't like the number of characters in the line, and also didn't like the `.find` being on a new line). They're pretty silly rules IMO - unless all of what JSLint enforces is what you *actually want*, if I were you, I'd consider using ESLint instead

Comment: So,  fiddling with both the code samples you provided, the second option will make JSLint fairly happy, but I should have noticed, you supplied a function in the second example, and JSLint Does not like that, ```Don't make function within a loop. });```

Comment: I don't see a loop here, is this whole code segment inside a loop? If so, probably good to extract it into a separate function (maybe named `setMatchingButton`) and then call that function on each iteration

Comment: I am about to just ignore all of JSLint and just focus on ESLint if it continues to be overly complicated just to make JSLint happy. There is no "reason" I have to have clean JSLint Code. I was more looking for understanding and seeing if I could do it. Personal Ambition I guess. ;)

Comment: Okay, so moving the matching to a new function is a way around that warning, wow. Good idea.
I should have mentioned that. I was just trying to show as little code as possible.

Comment: I am going to accept this as an overall solution, I am switching to using Primarily just ESLint, instead of keeping up with JSLint's as you put it opinionated responses, I also installed JSHint and this seems much better. Although, I could not get the JSLint in Brackets to accept const, but on the jslint site it has no warnings for using const. So I am assuming it is an issue with JSLint in Brackets. Could you please put using ESLint is probably the better way to go, and stop using JSLint in the answer somewhere.

Comment: I even updated the question to fit your answer even suggesting dropping JSLint